# "ValueError: shapes not aligned" while doing OLS regression on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I was trying to run an OLS regression on a DataFrame I had but I got this error:

> ValueError: shapes (48,34) and (48,34) not aligned: 34 (dim 1) != 48 (dim 0)

I'm not sure how to fix the alignment. I have included the OLS code I tried running and a picture of the DataFrame output. The entire DataFrame has 4 columns and 48 rows.

[image: DataFrame output]

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
result = sm.ols(formula="price ~ ownership + shipping + title", data=sold1).fit()
result.summary()
```

Comment: @nazul is `sold1` already a dataframe? can you share the shape, use `np.shape(sold1)`

Comment: check the dtypes of your data frame. It should be numeric except for categorical variables. My guess is that your price column are strings/object.

Answer (score 2):

Had the similar issue while running the linear regression in a loop for calculating the vif for factors. As mentioned by Josef in the comments, the reason was, i am having two columns as 'object' while rest were 'int'. Removed those two 'Object' column and it worked.

Comment: so i checked my data and it has this type -CategoricalDtype(categories=[1, 2, 3, 4], ordered=True . How Do i deal with it ? just to numeric ?